# Create a list from a string in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I'm looking to create a list of characters using a string as my source.  I did a bit of googling and came up with nothing so then I wrote a function that did what I wanted:

```
(defn list-from-string [char-string]
  (loop [source char-string result ()]
    (def result-char (string/take 1 source))
    (cond
     (empty? source) result
     :else (recur (string/drop 1 source) (conj result result-char)))))
```

But looking at this makes me feel like I must be missing a trick.

1. Is there a core or contrib function that does this for me?  Surely I'm just being dumb right?
2. If not is there a way to improve this code?
3. Would the same thing work for numbers too?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can just use **seq** function to do this:

```
user=> (seq "aaa")
(\a \a \a)
```

for numbers you can use "dumb" solution, something like:

```
user=> (map (fn [^Character c] (Character/digit c 10)) (str 12345))
(1 2 3 4 5)
```

P.S. strings in clojure are 'seq'able, so you can use them as source for any sequence processing functions - map, for, ...

Comment: Hi! What is the meaning of [^Character c]?  is ^Character to use Character/digit inside?

Comment: this is type hint, without it the clojure will use reflection to determine the argument type. This makes the function slightly faster...

Answer (score 23):

if you know the input will be letters, just use

```
user=> (seq "abc")
(\a \b \c)
```

for numbers, try this

```
user=> (map #(Character/getNumericValue %) "123")
(1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 6):

Edit: Oops, thought you wanted a list of *different* characters. For that, use the core function "frequencies".

```
clojure.core/frequencies
([coll])
  Returns a map from distinct items in coll to the number of times they appear.
```

Example:

```
user=> (frequencies "lazybrownfox")
{\a 1, \b 1, \f 1, \l 1, \n 1, \o 2, \r 1, \w 1, \x 1, \y 1, \z 1}
```

Then all you have to do is get the keys and turn them into a string (or not).

```
user=> (apply str (keys (frequencies "lazybrownfox")))
"abflnorwxyz"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't want to get the frequencies but I was interested in the tip none-the-less.

Answer (score 0):

```
(apply str (set "lazybrownfox")) => "abflnorwxyz"
```